# Cast shadow without rendering object

Tags: lighting, udk, shadows

I'm new to UDK, and am using it to develop a survival-horror game based heavily on shadows.

My question is short:  is there a way to create an actor that, when rendered, ONLY renders its shadow (not itself)?

If UDK can't do this, is there any other engine (Unity, CryEngine, Source) that can?

Comment: I googled "udk make object invisible except for shadow" and within 5 seconds got [this forum thread](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/771985-solved-Shadows-without-source-mesh) that seems to tell how to do it.

Comment: @NathanReed Fantastic!  Google can be so picky...  Post as (a little bit better-formatted) answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You can post it as an answer yourself, if you've verified it works.  I don't use UDK or have a copy to test with, so I can't.